# Django TestCase creating new test_ functions with exec and setattr in setUp()

Tags: django, django-testing

The code below is intended to get programmatically created tests to run, which isn't happening.

```
class TestAdminGetViews(TestCase):

  def setUp(self):
    self.factory = RequestFactory()
    self.admin_user = models.UserManager.create_user(email='test@test.com',password='12387343ad!'
        ,user_type=utils.UserTypes.admin.name)
    self.client = Client()  

    #create the test methods programmatically where URLNames.object.name = view.name

    for url in utils.URLNames: #an Enum object

        #is there a view associated with with this URLName?
        if callable(getattr(views,url.name)):
#placeholder code just to see if tests run
            str_function = '''def test_{}(self):\n\tself.assertIs(True,True)\nglobal my_function\nmy_function = test_{}'''.format(url.name, url.name)               
            exec( str_function )
            print( my_function )
            setattr(self,'test_' + url.name,my_function)

    #factory, admin_user, client and all the functions show themselves
    #as being attached to self
    print(str(self.__dict__))
```

The print function shows that the code runs "successfully". The dictionary contains factory, admin_user and client, all of which are accessable in the hard-coded test_ functions. The programmatically created functions also show in the dictionary with the correct name and function name.

However, the Django test environment does not run the programmatically created functions. Why?

**A little background color**:
My last staging deployment had an undetected issue with GET requests. I'd like to avoid those simple errors in the future with tests. Instead of writing a new test_function() for every view, I'd like to create GET view tests programmatically.

Comment: why do you need to create the test_ in first place? your for loop with many test options could run in single test_

Comment: Because in the event of multiple failures, I would only get a report of the first failure.

Also, I realize that I should be running this code in setUpTestData(cls), but I still get the same issue.

Comment: you could run the inside of the for loop in `try, except` and `yield` the errors if any

Answer (score 0):

you can try to run the test as follows... it is just demonstration that the for loop can print traceback... i think with your string method test_ and trying to say to python it is function wont work...

```
import traceback
from django.test import TestCase

class MyTest(TestCase):

    def test_views(self):

        any_error = False
        for url in range(0, 3):
            try:
                print("running: " + str(url))
                # run my test here
                # ...
                self.assertTrue(False) # fail on purpose

            except Exception as e:
                print(str(e))
                any_error = True
                traceback.print_exc()

        if any_error is True:
            raise RuntimeError("some test fails")
```

Comment: Good idea. I tried with both setUpClass and setUpTestData. Neither worked.

Comment: i edited my answer, i think you current approach with `str_function` wont work